# Setting domain-less cookies in iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies, subdomain

I have a website that sets a cookie on let's say *www.domain.com* called *aCookie*. This cookie needs to be retrieved from other sub-domains so I'm setting the domain of the cookie to *.domain.com*.

I need to read and write the cookie from an iFrame that links to *sub.domain.com*. They are on the same domain so there is no cross-site restriction or anything of the sort.

The weird thing is that if I write the cookie in www.domain.com and then try to change it's value from sub.domain.com a second cookie gets created with the same name but with the domain set to sub.domain.com, even if I explicitly set the domain to .domain.com.

After this happens the weirdness begins because it will not be read or it will be set on one of the cookies but read from the other cookie.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it, thanks?

```
Cookie.Set("directDepositMethod", directDepositMethod, { expires: 1, secure: true, path: '/', domain: ".domain.com" });
```

where set does:

```
 if (typeof value != "undefined") { // name and value given, set cookie
            options = options || {};
            if (value === null) {
                value = String.Empty;
                options.expires = -1;
            }
            var expires = String.Empty;
            if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == "number" || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
                var date;
                if (typeof options.expires == "number") {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                } else {
                    date = options.expires;
                }
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            }
            // CAUTION: Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
            // in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
            // in the packed version for some reason...
            var path = options.path ? "; path=" + (options.path) : "";
            var domain = options.domain ? "; domain=" + (options.domain) : "";
            var secure = options.secure ? "; secure" : "";
            document.cookie = [name, "=", encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join("");
        } else { // only name given, get cookie
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != String.Empty) {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + "=")) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
```

Comment: how are you setting/reading the cookie, care to show your code?

Comment: Not sure what might be going wrong there. However that cookie function does look a little overly complicated. I've used [these get/set cookie functions](https://gist.github.com/Novocaine88/39d81f73b2c0da095651) for a long time and they've not had issues transferring through from the main domain to sub domains.

Comment: also, in case you're not aware, there's a handy extension for Chrome that makes viewing cookies nice and quick, it could help you check the cookies being set are getting the right values; http://www.editthiscookie.com/